# Converting an advanced query from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

Still getting used to LINQ syntax, and have come across this query that I need to create in LINQ - but not exactly sure how.

```
SELECT *,
   (SELECT 1 FROM Applications 
   WHERE Applications.jID = Jobs.ID 
   AND Applications.uID = @uID) AS Applied 
FROM [Jobs]
```

Playing in LinqPad, but the interface isn't really helping (at least with what I can see).

Comment: Can you describe the goal of your query in English for us?

Comment: Sure. It's providing a list of jobs (the * from Jobs part). The (Select 1...) returns if the current user has applied to the job.  So, the result set should be:
[ID], [JobTitle], [Location], [1 or null]

Comment: You're trying to use a subquery but it's not really necessary. You can accomplish what you need with a left outer join. See here for outer joins with LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: @sinni800: Please remove your comment. It is not constructive in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the link provided by Paul Sasik, and his advice that you're after a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`,  this query should meet your requirements;

```
var query = from job in jobs
            join app in applications on job.ID equals app.jID into grouped
            from subApp in grouped.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Job = job, Applied = (subApp != null) };
```

**EDIT**:
To filter by user, update the query as follows;

```
var query = from job in jobs
    join app in
    (
        from userApp in applications where userApp.uID == uID select userApp
    ) on job.ID equals app.jID into grouped
    from subApp in grouped.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Job = job, Applied = (subApp != null) };
```

I personally would have reverted to just using the .Where() method directly at this point, but just thought I'd keep everything consistent and continue using the query syntax.

Comment: This is what I came up with with Paul's suggestion as well. However, I'm getting repeated Job listings with the Applied column displaying "True" for every job.

Comment: What does your data look like? Is there a further filter that's required, such as a userID? The code as given above will return duplicate job rows if there is more than one application for any given job. If we can narrow the results by UserId or something, then the results should be more useful (assuming a user can only apply for the same job once).

Comment: Ah, yes. We've forgotten about the userID in all of this.  In the Applications table, there is a uID field....

Comment: Where would the 'where' clause go in this query?

Comment: That's the one. Thanks, Chris. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
var jobs = from j in this.db.Jobs
           where !j.Applications.Any(x => x.UserId == currentUserId)
           select j;
```

Comment: I still want to show the jobs that the user hasn't applied for, hence the extra column being added to the result set.

Comment: This example performs an inner join and filters out records that do not match. The OP needs all records from `Jobs` with a flag value for the ones that have a connection to `Applications`.

Comment: My bad on the misunderstanding. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the tool [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) -- which converts SQL to Linq code.  It's not free but there is a 10 day trial.

[image]